# Why does the File and FileStream API fail to write binary data with no exception thrown on Ubuntu?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, io, ubuntu-18.04

I have an application which I have tried to target both .NET Core 2.1 and .NET Core 3.1 for build while still exhibiting this issue. I am replicating the file streaming process that happens from our API (an Ubuntu 18.04.4 VM) to our storage server (also an Ubuntu VM), except it goes from the storage to our OCR service (a third Ubuntu VM). The Ubuntu VMs all have the latest version of .NET Core installed. This file streaming process works on a homegrown "file service" protocol which I would rather avoid explaining in great detail, but suffice to say that there is a "**Create**" message which tells the recipient to create a file handle and write the first packet of data (packets are up to 64 kB), and upon receiving this "**Create**" message, a consumer is initialized which consumes the rest of the file data as "**Append**" messages from a separate queue until a "**Close**" message is received (contains no payload). This seemed to work great until I actually tried to perform basic manipulations on the file received on OCR (namely, splitting the pages out of a PDF document) and realized that the file is corrupt. On a hunch I checked the size of the file on the OCR server, and sure enough it is exactly 64 kB smaller than the original file. This issue has never occurred in the API-to-storage part of the pipeline. I have checked our storage server to ensure that the data is not corrupted when transferring from the API by downloading it.

On another hunch, I decided to comment out the code which writes the **Append** message payloads to the file to ensure that the missing packet was not the original **Create** payload. I was correct, and after processing just the **Create** message, the file is 0 bytes. I have checked the length of the **Create** payload and also printed it out as a hash to ensure it's not all 0s for whatever reason -- no issues there. However, every time I get to writing the bytes to the actual file, **no data is written and no error is thrown**. The file handle and directory is created with a size of 0 bytes and all log messages are printed. I will now post all the different ways I have tried to write this initial 64 kB of data to the file:

**File API**

```
public FileServiceResponseEnvelope Create(FileServiceMessageEnvelope message, string filePath)
        {
            var response = CreateResponse(message);
            var payload = SerializationHelper.DeserializeObject<SecureMessage>(message.SignedPayload).Payload;

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                // 23 is enough for the first 8 bytes and the hyphens separating them.
                _logger.LogStatement($"Creating new file at [{filePath}] while appending [{payload.Length} bytes] and hash that starts with {BitConverter.ToString(payload).Substring(0, 23)}...", LogLevel.Trace, nameof(Create));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, payload);
            }
            else
            {
                var error = $"File at [{filePath}] already exists and cannot be created.";
                response.ErrorMessage = error;
                response.Success = false;
                throw new InvalidOperationException(error);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

**FileStream API**

```
public FileServiceResponseEnvelope Create(FileServiceMessageEnvelope message, string filePath)
        {
            var response = CreateResponse(message);
            var payload = SerializationHelper.DeserializeObject<SecureMessage>(message.SignedPayload).Payload;

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                // 23 is enough for the first 8 bytes and the hyphens separating them.
                _logger.LogStatement($"Creating new file at [{filePath}] while appending [{payload.Length} bytes] and hash that starts with {BitConverter.ToString(payload).Substring(0, 23)}...", LogLevel.Trace, nameof(Create));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    stream.Write(payload, 0, message.Count);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var error = $"File at [{filePath}] already exists and cannot be created.";
                response.ErrorMessage = error;
                response.Success = false;
                throw new InvalidOperationException(error);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

**FileStream API using WriteByte**

```
public FileServiceResponseEnvelope Create(FileServiceMessageEnvelope message, string filePath)
        {
            var response = CreateResponse(message);
            var payload = SerializationHelper.DeserializeObject<SecureMessage>(message.SignedPayload).Payload;

            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                // 23 is enough for the first 8 bytes and the hyphens separating them.
                _logger.LogStatement($"Creating new file at [{filePath}] while appending [{payload.Length} bytes] and hash that starts with {BitConverter.ToString(payload).Substring(0, 23)}...", LogLevel.Trace, nameof(Create));
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath));;
                using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    stream.Seek(message.Position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    foreach (byte b in payload)
                    {
                        _logger.LogStatement($"Writing [{b}] to file...", LogLevel.Trace, nameof(Create));
                        stream.WriteByte(b);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var error = $"File at [{filePath}] already exists and cannot be created.";
                response.ErrorMessage = error;
                response.Success = false;
                throw new InvalidOperationException(error);
            }

            return response;
        }
```

For reference, here is the **Append** message handler, which works.

```
AppendStream = new FileStream(DestinationPath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);

...

public FileServiceResponseEnvelope Append(FileServiceMessageEnvelope message, FileStream appendStream)
        {
            var response = CreateResponse(message);
            var payload = SerializationHelper.DeserializeObject<SecureMessage>(message.SignedPayload).Payload;

            _logger.LogStatement($"Appending [{message.Count} bytes] to [{appendStream.Name}]. Actual length: [{payload.Length} bytes]", LogLevel.Trace, nameof(Append));
            if (appendStream == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"The filestream was null and therefore cannot be appended to.");

            appendStream.Write(payload, 0, message.Count);

            return response;
        }
```

`AppendStream` is a member of the consumer class and `AppendStream.Dispose()` is called when the **Close** message mentioned earlier is received.

Any help with this would be much appreciated. I have also tried invoking `Flush(true)` and `Close()` even though I'm about 99% sure those are already called on disposal at the end of the `using` block. I'm running completely dry on things to try here and am starting to be convinced that this is some sort of System.IO library bug. All of the code above runs without errors, but no data is written on the "Create" handler. My only remaining idea is that something else is taking control of the file handle, but I tried to be careful to write all of this part of the code synchronously and driven by events signaled when the last piece is finished (for example the file is only processed by the actual OCR service, when the "Done" event on the consumer is invoked, which only happens when **Close** is received). I can't find anything else that might take control of that file handle in my code as of yet.  Apologies for the long-winded post, but I felt I had to lay it all out to show how stubborn this issue is and what I've tried.

Comment: Exactly 64 kib smaler? Maybe you start the 2nd phase of the writing operations (the ones involving the Append messages) at position 0, rather then 64 kib? This whole design is kinda wierd. I mean a create order that writes, then a bunch of further writes? This is just screaming for using the wrong index by accident.

Comment: It's something I inherited and this is the first time I've worked with file streaming, professionally. However, this system has been proven to work many times over. I use the exact same code in the process of moving the files from the API to storage. Specifically the FileStream version of the code. We even move encrypted files over it. It's useful in the context of our message queuing framework, RabbitMQ, because all the upload data can be put in a separate queue, and the main queue can be kept clear for CRUD "actions" (read, delete, etc).

Comment: Thinking about it, writing *something* also has a advantage: It makes certain you can *actually* write. Networks and disks tend to be rather unreliable in that regard. And just because you got a open handle, does not mean it will actually work. And even if it worked last time, that does not mean it will work this time again. Maybe the code is too agressive catching Exceptions? There are two articles on the mater I link often: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Christopher I have recently refactored all of the exception handling in our code and it is very thorough in logging. There were none being thrown. However I took your earlier suggestion and decided to rewrite the protocol so that Create messages bore no payload, and all of the writing is performed on the "Append" action, with only the file handle created on "Create." That actually fixed it. I still have no idea why the "Create" write didn't work, since it worked as-is on another machine and there seemed to be no logical reason for it. Unfortunately I think it may remain a mystery forever now.

Comment: Sorry for the double post, but if you want to post your earlier suggestion as an answer, I will mark it

Comment: So it iwas one of those Problems? https://xkcd.com/2259/ | https://xkcd.com/2261/

Comment: Yes, it was one of those problems. I've taken to believing in the Omnissiah. My OCR server's machine spirit was extremely upset and only satisfied with over 32 hours of work on its behalf. I will recite the Litany of Intact Binary Data next time.